# OpenLayers: can't i get features of VectorSource outside of event listener?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-5

i'm trying to show only a certain feature from my Vector Source. so i make a function like this:

```
function showUtility(id) {
        utilitiesSource.forEach(function(i) {
            //console.log(i.getFeatures());
            i.forEachFeature(function(f) {
                if (f.getProperties().id == id) {
                    f.setStyle(null);
                } else {
                    f.setStyle([]);
                }
            });
        });
}
```

where the utilitiesSource comes from:

```
utilitiesSource = [];

var utilitySource = new ol.source.Vector({
                format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
                projection: 'EPSG:4326',
                url: 'someUrl',
                extractStyles: false
        });

utilitiesSource.push(utilitySource);
```

**the problem is** `console.log(i.getFeatures())` in `showUtility()` always gives empty array although it's fine if i was using it in an eventlistener like these:

```
    var selectCtrl = new ol.control.Select({
        source: utilitiesSource,
        property: $(".options select").val(),
        selectLabel: 'Cari',
        addLabel: 'Tambah Kondisi',
        allLabel: 'Cocokkan Semua',
        attrPlaceHolder: 'atribut',
        valuePlaceHolder: 'nilai'
    });

 selectCtrl.on('select', function(e) {
        select.getFeatures().clear();
        utilitiesSource.forEach(function(i) {
            //console.log(i.getFeatures()); --> gives array of feature
            i.forEachFeature(function(f) {
                f.setStyle([]);
            });
        })
        e.features.forEach(function(f) {
            f.setStyle(null);
        });
    });

    var bar = new ol.control.Bar({ 
      group: true,
      controls: [
        selectCtrl,
        new ol.control.Button({
          html: '<i class="fa fa-undo" ></i>',
          title: 'Reset',
          handleClick: function() {
            select.getFeatures().clear();
            utilitiesSource.forEach(function(i) {
                //console.log(i.getFeatures()); --> gives array of feature
                i.getFeatures().forEach(function(f) {
                    f.setStyle(null);
                });
            })
          }
        })
     ]});
```

and if i use browser's console and execute `utilitiesSource.forEach(function(i) { i.getFeatures().forEach(function(j){ if (j.getProperties().id == 100) {j.setStyle(null);} else {j.setStyle([])} });});` i get what i want

why is that? why can't i get the features in showUtility(id)?

Comment: Are you sure that vector sources have loaded their features when you call the `showUtility(id)` method?

Comment: i'm sure, my layers which source is the utilitiesSource's content showing perfectly. i also have tried call the function in the last row of my code, but still no luck

Comment: How can you be sure that all of your sources has been loaded successfully. This is an asynchronous task and has nothing to do with calling your code at last line.

Comment: sorry, i didn't know it was asynchronous task and i was sure because my layers shows features from that source just fine. so, should i use getState() or on('render' ,function()) ?

Comment: First of all try to call your function once you see all vectors in your map , just to make sure that this is your problem. And then yes you need call `vectorSource.on('change', function(e) { if (vectorSource.getState() == 'ready') { ...call your method....`

Comment: ah, you're right, the vector sources in utilitiesSource gives empty array because it wasn't ready when i called it.
so i fix my code like this :
`utilitiesSource.forEach(function(i) {
            i.on('change', function(e) {
                if (i.getState() == 'ready') {
                    i.forEachFeature(function(f) {
                        f.setStyle([]);
                    });
                }
            });
        });`
but, why is it gives `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` ?

Comment: Your code may be in a loop if making changes to features causes another change event in the source. A better event to use might be addfeature `i.on('addfeature', function(e) { e.feature.setStyle([]); });`

Comment: How many sources do you add on your map? This sounds a recursive problem.  Can you make a fiddle to demonstrate your case? It is hard to identify your problem as long as we dont have the full image of your case.

Comment: @Mike thanks so much, it worked. yay!

Comment: @pavlos only 16. yeah, i also thought it was a recursive problem. but i didn't call a function inside it's own function. so, i don't know why it was recursive. the error pops out when i called `f.setStyle([])`, because if i replace it with console.log, no error shown

Comment: anyway @pavlos you should put your answer in the Answer section so i can mark it as answer

Comment: Glad you found your way out. No need for amenities , thanks anyway.